# Is it possible to buy a legal third-party MacBook (Pro) charger?

Tags: macbook-pro, magsafe

Apple owns the `MagSafe` patents - I realize this. On eBay, there are a ton of chargers, but no doubt of dubious origins. Are there any third party creators of chargers?

If a company wanted to create a new charger for the MacBook line, can they legally do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple does not license the MagSafe technology. So a company could not legally do so. You can read more about it over at Wikipedia.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MagSafe

On a side note: Apple has recently started allowing trade ins on old iphone/ipad chargers after a few aftermarket units have created some safety issues.

http://www.apple.com/support/usbadapter-takeback/

Comment: This is ridiculous, their own chargers are so fragile. Today I'll have to purchase my third charger since buying this in 2014. My Dell laptop's charger (previous computer) is in a better shape than the new mbp's. Can't help but think their entire 'sleek design' is a load of crap.

Answer (score 3):

I have long-term professional expertise regarding electrical safety.
Legal power supplies have extensive and expensive certification and testing and manufacturing controls to ensure the user's safety.
Some of the most safety sensitive aspects are:

1. Isolation Voltage - How high a voltage may exist between the computer electronics and the mains wiring without a breakdown occurring.
2. Leakage Current - How much current can flow through the power supply (and ultimately you) if you make contact with a grounded contact or even a live wire while you are contacting the computer electronics.
3. Fire or burns

I will not claim that the "knock-off" supplies have NOT had the testing, but you decide for yourself if you think that Chinese manufactured supplies, even those bearing CE, UL, or CSA marks have actually passed or even been tested with the ultra-expensive tests and whether the manufacturing operation is well-controlled enough to guarantee that the product has not been modified.
How much would you spend to ensure that you or your child is not electrocuted?